# Changing controls names color in code - Visual Studio 2019

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, colors, customization

I googled it but I didn’t find a pertinent result.
in VS 2019 Community, I customized some colors from menu Tools > Options > Fonts and Colors, but I didn't figure out how to change the color of the controls names.
I.e., if a window contains a label named myLabel and my code contains `myLabel.Content`, what do I have to do in order to get `myLabel` displayed in a custom color in code editor? I tried various options but without success.
Hope someone has already faced this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of application? WinForms, Asp.net, WPF, mobile app?

Comment: That "name" is a field, i.e. a member variable. The fact that it refers to a control isn't relevant. The code editor doesn't distinguish fields that refer to controls and other fields. Basically, what you're trying to do isn't possible because it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: That said, if you want to change the colour for all fields (not just controls) then there might be an option for that. I don't know as I haven't looked but at least now you know what to look for.

Comment: If you want to change the font color of your label in winform, try: `myLabel.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 200, 200)`

Comment: Thank you @jmcilhinney, I understood! I already customized the color for all fields, I was wondering if it was possibile to treat separately controls but now I know it’s not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you want to change the color of the label name in your editor, [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qzvx.png). However this is considered plain text so the only way to do so is by changing the *"Plain Text"* settings in *Tools > Options > Fonts And Colors*, but this changes it for everything else that is considered plain text too.

Comment: Thank you, I understood. So unfortunately it’s not possibile at the moment.